# HTML - Set a default value for select that can't be chosen again once changed, and have the width of the select field change accordingly

Tags: html, css

So here is my issue. I've found the folowing code, which hides the default option of a select once it has been changed:

```
<select>
  <option hidden disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is a fiddle to see this in action:

```html
<select>
  <option hidden disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

The issue I have, is that  I want the select to shrink once the default option is no longer available, because as of now there is a lot of wasted space. Is it possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: What do you mean by shrinking the select? can you describe the requirements in brief?

Comment: The default option is much wider than the actual choices, and even once it is gone the select retains it can still be chosen. What I'm trying to do is have the width of the select change to fit the widest available option.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width manually for each option on change so It'll automatically change the width for all the sizes selected at the moment.

check the fiddle below,

```js
$('.myClass').change(function(){
  var option_text = $(this).find('option:selected').text()
  var $appends = $('<select/>').append($('<option/>').text(option_text))
  $(this).after($appends)
  $(this).width($appends.width())
  $appends.remove()
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="myClass">
  <option hidden disabled selected value">--select an option--</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can this be done without JQuery with just standard Javascript (or typescript)?